# Docker hub + OSX nodes: Selenium Grid DefaultRemoteProxy unknown Connection timed out

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Currently, I am able to create a docker hub and connect additional docker nodes. 
The hub and nodes are all AWS instances. The hub has OpenVPN installed.

Currently, I am attempting to connect a physical Mac Mini with the role node.

The docker nodes are able to connect to the hub just fine. However, when I attempt to connect the physical node, it outputs

```
16:27:29.143 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

When I view the grid/console it displays

```
DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to <mac_mini_ip>:port [mac_mini_ip] failed: Connection timed out
```

Since OpenVPN is running on the hub which is an AWS node, we are able to connect to that instance using the OpenVPN config which is on the mac_mini.

Here is what I have tried, all resulting in the default remote proxy connection timed out error

I am able to do a `wget <hub_ip>:4444/grid/register` and it returns a `200`
When I ssh into the hub, and do a telnet mac_mini_ip:port i get a 403 Forbidden for Proxy

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub
<hub_ip>:4444/grid/register -role node -nodeConfig path_to_config
```

I'm a little confused as to what my actual arguments in the config file have to be in order to resolve this DefaultRemoteProxy error

```
"configuration": {

"unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 30000,

"role": "node",

"remoteHost":"mac_mini_ip:6666", <- there are other docker nodes connected and I don't want to conflict ports, so I chose 6666 here but I'm assuming it can be a different port

"hubHost":"hub_ip",

"timeout": 30000,

"host": "mac_mini_ip",

"capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",

"hubPort": 4444,

"url": "<hub_url>:4444/grid/register",

"newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,

"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",

"port": 6666,

"register": true,

"hub":"hub_ip:4444/grid/register",
```

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/254

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using the docker option --net=host